# How to reference functions from other function files in ASP.NET Web Pages 2?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, razor, razor-2, asp.net-webpages

Here's the situation:

Let's say I have two files in App_Code containing blocks of functions in each:

Here's sample function #1 in file AppCode/File1.cshtml:

```
@functions {
  public static Boolean getTrue() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here's sample function #2 in file AppCode/File2.cshtml:

```
@functions {
  public static Boolean getFalse() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I can reference the either functions in CSHTML files from my root folder via @File1.getTrue() or @File2.getFalse().

However, can I call @File2.getFalse() in AppCode/File1.cshtml so that:

```
@functions {
   public static Boolean getTrue() {
     return (!@File2.getFalse());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in a function marked with the `helper` keyword is pure C#. Therefore you should remove the Razor @ sign. That should only be used to render server-side variables and expression results to the browser.

```
 @functions {
   public static Boolean getTrue() {
     return (!File2.getFalse());
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. You are right, in that `@` should be left out. It turns out the problem was that IntelliSense in VS2012 wasn't picking up the second function file and it was underlining the functions with red squigglies. I mistook that as not being able to access the functions however it was compiling and working correctly.